# How do you use C++0x raw strings with GCC 4.5?

Tags: c++, g++, c++11

This page says that GCC 4.5 has C++ raw string literals: http://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html

But when I try to use the syntax from this page: [http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/C++0xFAQ.html#raw-strings](http://www2.research.att.com/%7Ebs/C++0xFAQ.html#raw-strings)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string s = R"[\w\\\w]";

}
```

I get this error:

```
/opt/local/bin/g++-mp-4.5 -std=gnu++0x -O3    rawstr.cc   -o rawstr  
rawstr.cc:9:19: error: invalid character '\' in raw string delimiter  
rawstr.cc:9:5: error: stray 'R' in program
```

What is the right syntax for raw strings?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Try

```
R"(\w\\\w)";
```

The delimiters `[…]` were changed to `(…)` in [n3077](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2010/n3077.html).